# ASP.NET - jquery ui connected sortable save to database

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

Okay so I have a jQuery UI connected sortable on my page.  Everything works good.  They are being dynamically created from the database.  So  I am using an ASP Repeater to populate the ul.  This all works great.  Now I need to save the updated lists to the database.  This has proved to be very difficult.

```
$(function () {
        $("#include, #exclude").sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            dropOnEmpty: true,
        });
        $("#include, #exclude").disableSelection();
    });
```

This is what I have for the jQuery.  I think there may need to be more here, but I cannot seem to figure out what it is.  We have found a way to loop through the repeater items and get them into a DataBoundLiteralControl, but every time it uses the old order and not the new order.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
           $("#sortable1 li").each(function (idx, li) {
          var idInputs = $(li).children(".id");
          var nameInputs = $(li).children(".name");//if an ItemName input is used
        $(idInputs).attr("id", "Items_" + idx + "__ItemId");
        $(idInputs).attr("name", "Items[" + idx + "].ItemId");
        //if an ItemName input is used
        $(nameInputs).attr("id", "Items_" + idx + "__ItemName");
        $(nameInputs).attr("name", "Items[" + idx + "].ItemName");
         });
```

see this link :
http://jgibson.com/?p=59